# Unix script to search for a file in user defined directory

Tags: shell, unix

I need to make an unix script to check for a file in a user defined directory i.e. script will take in the file name (e.g. abc.txt) and will also input directory from the user (e.g. /home/user/abc) & the script will check if that particular file (abc.txt) is available in that directory or not.

I have tried using:-

```
echo "Enter your directory"
read directory
echo "Enter file name"
read name
if [ -s $directory/$name ]
 then 
echo 0
else
echo "File not available"
```

Comment: Did that not work? What's your question exactly?

Comment: use `ls $directory | grep $name`

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia No, don't [parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The better way of doing this is `if [[ -r "${directory}/${name}" ]]; then ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
find $directory -name "$name" | egrep '.*'
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo 0
else 
    echo "File not available"
fi
```

OR you could use

```
if [ -e $directory/$name ]
```

To check whether file exists or not.

Comment: Note that the `find` method will also find `${directory}/some/sub/directory/${name}`, which may not be intended...

Comment: Yeah agree in that case OP might need to use maxDepth as 1.

Comment: I am getting "No such file or directory" error when I run this script.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look on the unix stack exchange site, this should be more helpful to you:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63387/single-command-to-check-if-file-exists-and-print-custom-message-to-stdout

this might be helpful:

```
system("[ ! -e file ]; echo $?")
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is almost correct, here is a fixed/enhanced version:

```
printf "Enter your directory : "
read directory
printf "Enter file name      : "
read name
if [ -f "$directory/$name" ] ; then 
    echo "File found"
else
    echo "File not found"
fi
```